# Find distinct row based on date criteria

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For below data frame I need to find a single row per ids
since ids are duplicated. Here is the logic to get a single row

- Get the row with max dt2
- If dt2 are same get the row with max dt1
- If dt2 and dt1 are same get 1 random row

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(
  ("a", "du", Date.valueOf("2020-01-04"),Date.valueOf("2020-02-07") ),
  ("a", "xx", Date.valueOf("2020-01-01"), Date.valueOf("2020-03-01")),
  ("a", "xy", Date.valueOf("2020-01-01"), Date.valueOf("2020-02-01")),
  ("b", "ww", Date.valueOf("2020-01-05"), Date.valueOf("2020-02-25")),
  ("b", "nn", Date.valueOf("2020-01-04"), Date.valueOf("2020-02-25")),
  ("c", "qq", Date.valueOf("2020-02-21"), Date.valueOf("2020-03-09")),
  ("c", "rr", Date.valueOf("2020-02-21"), Date.valueOf("2020-03-09"))
).toDF("id", "code", "dt1", "dt2")


data.show()


+---+----+----------+----------+
| id|code|       dt1|       dt2|
+---+----+----------+----------+
|  a|  du|2020-01-04|2020-02-07|
|  a|  xx|2020-01-01|2020-03-01|
|  a|  xy|2020-01-01|2020-02-01|
|  b|  ww|2020-01-05|2020-02-25|
|  b|  nn|2020-01-04|2020-02-25|
|  c|  qq|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|
|  c|  rr|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|
+---+----+----------+----------+


output needed:

+---+----+----------+----------+
| id|code|       dt1|       dt2|
+---+----+----------+----------+
|  a|  xx|2020-01-01|2020-03-01| -- row with max dt2
|  b|  ww|2020-01-05|2020-02-25| -- max dt1 since dt2s are same
|  c|  rr|2020-02-21|2020-03-09| -- randomw row since both dt1s and dt2s are same
```

My attempt:

```
val byId = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"dt2", $"dt1" desc)
val idByMaxdate = data.select('*, rank().over(byId) as 'rank).where($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")
idByMaxdate.show()


+---+----+----------+----------+
| id|code|       dt1|       dt2|
+---+----+----------+----------+
|  c|  qq|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|
|  c|  rr|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|
|  b|  ww|2020-01-05|2020-02-25|
|  a|  xy|2020-01-01|2020-02-01|
+---+----+----------+----------+
```

Got this far but not sure how to get only one row for ids that have same dt1 and dt2 appreciate any help!

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)

Answer (score 1):

There are several window aggregate functions like...

`rank`, `dense_rank`, `percent_rank`, `ntile`, `row_number` [see databrics docs](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

you have to use `row_number` out of this as per requirement read docs and differences.

```
 val window = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"dt2", $"dt1" desc)

  data.withColumn("rownumber", row_number().over(window))
    .filter($"rownumber" === 1)
    .drop("rownumber")
    .show(false)
 }
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----------+----------+
|id |code|dt1       |dt2       |
+---+----+----------+----------+
|c  |qq  |2020-02-21|2020-03-09|
|b  |ww  |2020-01-05|2020-02-25|
|a  |xy  |2020-01-01|2020-02-01|
+---+----+----------+----------+
```

To understand row_number, rank and dense_rank better way see this,

```
data
  .withColumn("rank", rank().over(window))
  .withColumn("dense_rank", dense_rank().over(window))
  .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window))
  .show()
```

```
+---+----+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
| id|code|       dt1|       dt2|rank|dense_rank|row_number|
+---+----+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
|  c|  qq|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|   1|         1|         1|
|  c|  rr|2020-02-21|2020-03-09|   1|         1|         2|
|  b|  nn|2020-01-04|2020-02-25|   1|         1|         1|
|  b|  ww|2020-01-05|2020-02-25|   2|         2|         2|
|  a|  xy|2020-01-01|2020-02-01|   1|         1|         1|
|  a|  du|2020-01-04|2020-02-07|   2|         2|         2|
|  a|  xx|2020-01-01|2020-03-01|   3|         3|         3|
+---+----+----------+----------+----+----------+----------+
```

In your `where` condition, you have 4 rows with same rank 1 so you are getting 4 rows.

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)